# HEAP Snapshot node.js: Don't understand timeout & ArrayBuffer object

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, heap-memory, snapshot

I'm having trouble finding the origin of a memory leak I have in my node.js application.

I'm using a HTTP server running on each worker of my cluster application. Each worker handles file download & upload and I can notice a huge memory leak (that can go to 6 to 8 GB in res memory).

I tried getting a heap snapshot of one of the worker leaking heavily and having trouble understanding it.

[image]

In the beginning of the dropdown list when selecting the first and heaviest JSArrayBufferData we can see that there's a Buffer that holds all the memory, but if I scroll down enough the Retained Size is also listed under " in Socket".

I don't really understand from the Snapshot if there are some socket in my application that retains file informations and causes the leak or if a timeout is causing huge trouble.

Any help understanding or pointing me toward more information about Heap Snapshot analysis would be greatly appreciated.